# how to copy object in powershell to variable in azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-functions, powershell-3.0

my problem is when i copy a value of object that contain multi lines  to variable in azure the value of this variable just the first line of this object like this 
when i run this in power shell

```
 $MyFile = Get-Content -Path 'DataFile.json'  | ConvertFrom-Json

 Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arrayObjects;]$MyFile"
```

my file json conatin this

```
 [
         {
             "nameIcon" :"VertexCart",
          "distributionGroupIdAndroid": "0e9d0222-9bf1-48c8-9444-4a47c284a268",
          "distributionGroupIdIos": "f9f9e340-9641-4223-a528-ab4e5fe57469",
           "ArtifactNameIos": "MEShop-ios",
           "ArtifactNameAndroid": "MEShop-apk",
           "AppSlugAndroid": "MEShop",
           "AppSlugIos": "MEShop-1"
 } ]
```

the value of the variable in azure (arrayObjects) is just '[' it the same of value of first line 
there is any way to copy all the json file to the variable in azure please help me ?

Comment: If I run your code snippet in Powershell Core (`pwsh.exe`)  then `$MyFile` is a _PSCustomObject_ and `"$MyFile"` is a non-empty string. In your _Windows Powershell 3.0_ (`powershell.exe`)  is another result:  `$MyFile` is an _array_ and `"$MyFile"` is an empty string. Maybe use `"$($MyFile[0])"`?

Comment: Did you try out below solution of @Yash Gupta-AIS? it seems working. You can mark it as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Did the below solution worked for you? If it did, please mark it as an Accepted answer so that it helps others as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it back to JSON format (using `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet) along with passing  `-Compress` parameter. This will omit the whitespaces and indented formatting from your JSON content so that you can easily parse the entire content (& not just the first line of JSON content).

Try something like this:

```
$MyFile = Get-Content -Path 'DataFile.json'  | ConvertFrom-Json
$NewFile = $MyFile | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arrayObjects;]$NewFile"
```